# Use multiple filter for Tiled layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tiles

I am using GeoServer & want to apply multiple filters for 'tiled layer'. Is it possible?

I checked [this documentation](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/enterprise/gwc.html) & I have researched on web regarding this but unable to find exact documentation

Comment: what sort of filter do you want to apply?

Comment: @IanTurton : I have year attribute contains many years & I want to filter only specific year ex. year=2018 AND year=2019. But its not working on my side. In addition, I guess how tiles will be classified based on this condition ?

Comment: You need YEAR=2018 **OR** YEAR=2019

Comment: @IanTurton : Agreed but what about tiles? Because I want to use specific year tiles in my ckan application, also dynamically I can not pass this , is that correct ?

Comment: did you read - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/layers.html#adding-a-filter

Comment: @IanTurton as per above link says that it get cached once so dynamic tiling is not possible. May be then for each layer I have to publish separate layers